# What is this git command saying?

Tags: git, github

What is the git command saying?  What is it-staging:master? The master part is throwing me off. How can a my branch it-staging have a master under/in it?

```
git push my-staging it-staging:master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `git push --help`, you will find a Example as following

```
git push origin HEAD:master
       Push the current branch to the remote ref matching master in the origin 
       repository. This form is convenient to push the current branch without
       thinking about its local name.
```

For your question, `it-staging:master` means push your local branch `it-staging` to remote branch `master`.